# Need help please about Dini derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

Do you think that the upper right-hand Dini derivative of any continuous real-valued function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ always exist and is finite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no its not finite allways. For example $$f(x)=x^{1/3}$$ has infinite upper right-hand Dini derivative at origin.
But  one can ask nore interesting question.

For any continuous real-valued function f:ℝ→ℝ Does there exist a point in which the upper right-hand Dini derivative is finite?